# Pure JavaScript Binary Manipulation

Tags: javascript, file, binaryfiles

As a personal project, I'm writing a 6502 emulator in JavaScript (HTML5 based). I'm porting some bits of it from a predecessor I created in C. To load in the files (ROMs in my case), I could use this C code:

```
unsigned char* buffer = calloc(1, 4096);
FILE* file = fopen("xyz", "rb");
fread(buffer, 1, 4096, file);
fclose(file);
```

and access it like this:

```
char firstChar = buffer[0];
short nextShort = (buffer[2] << 8) | buffer[1];
free(buffer);
```

Now, I need to be able to port this to JavaScript. For input, I can do something like this using a file input:

```
var file = document.getElementById("picker").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

From here, I have reader.result as a giant, base64 encoding of the file. I need a way to access the binary file as I did in the beginning C example, where I can simply get the values (or use simple bitwise operations)

I'm guessing the most feasible solution would be an array of values 0-255, but I just need access, regardless of how.

Comment: Bit manipulation is really not my thing, but I believe you should be reading the file into an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) with [FIleReader.readAsArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsArrayBuffer()).

Comment: Yup, that did the trick, closing this.

Comment: Let me suggest you something: add your last update as an answer, and accept your own answer. This can be valuable content for future visitors!

Comment: Thanks! And you even got 15 rep points in the process! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bfavaretto pointed me in the correct direction

```
var file = document.getElementById("picker").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
var buffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
```

Which can then be accessed as buffer[0] for the first byte.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of `simplebuf` library. It allows quick binary parsing/serialization and is purely written in javascript.

Example:

```
var layout = [
    sb.field("len", sb.type.uint(32)),
    sb.field("padding", sb.type.uint(32)),
    sb.field("id", sb.type.string_dynamic("len"))
];
var original = {len: 4, "padding": 999, "id": "1234"};
sb.write(buffer, 0, original, layout);
```

https://github.com/conceptacid/simplebuf.js